# Can I create an array like this in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var row = [ [{text: [“##”]},{text: [“  ”]}], [{text: [“  ”]},{text: [“##”]}] ];
```

The editor showed an error:

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

What's wrong? Why can't I create an array like this?

Comment: Can you point out how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace `“` with `"` (double quotes)

this is correct version of your array

```
var a = [ [{text: ["##"]},{text: ["  "]}], [{text: ["  "]},{text: ["##"]}] ]
```

Comment: @Sotra don't worry, it happens. Try http://www.jslint.com/ in future, it will help.

Comment: WOW THANKS for letting know about that!

Comment: Or use a plain text editor that uses the correct quote character. ;-)